# Use d3 library to read from json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, anychart

I have two different charts that use the same exact data. One uses json embedded in the html while the other reads a file.

I've been googling to see if I find examples where `anychart` reads from a json file or a web service. I have found nothing.

Since the 2nd chart reads `json` data using the `d3.json` call, I'm thinking that maybe it's possible to use that same function to read the data in the `anychart` chart.

So I'm including the `javascript` for both charts.

`anychart javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
      chart = anychart.fromJson(
        {chart: {type: "line",
          series:[{seriesType: "spline",
    data: [{x: "January", value: 10000},{x: "February", value: 12000},{x: "March", value: 18000}]}],                            
          container: "container"}} 
      ).draw();                             
    });     
</script>
```

`d3` that reads that from a `json` file. Maybe I can use this call to populate the report in the previous code?:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })
    .map(data);

    rect.filter(function(d) {
      return ("$" + d) in nest;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { 
      return color(nest[("$" + d)][0].open);
    })
});
```

Any help is appreciated. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: if it's the same data why aren't you saving it? And why do you need to read it from a file if it's already present in this html?

Comment: Because the data will be coming from a WCF service.

Comment: I use a file, and not a link, so that an excited member doesn't downvote the question for not including the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

There are https://api.anychart.com/7.13.1/anychart.data#loadJsonFile and https://api.anychart.com/7.13.1/anychart#fromJsonFile methods, they are a part of data adapter script.

Here are samples:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.1/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/data-adapter.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.13.1/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    <style>
      html, body, #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // To work with the data adapter you need to reference the data adapter script file from AnyChart CDN
    // (https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/data-adapter.min.js for latest or https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.11.1/data-adapter.min.js for the versioned file)

    // Load JSON data and create a chart by JSON data.
    anychart.data.loadJsonFile("https://cdn.anychart.com/charts-data/data_json.json", function (data) {

        chart = anychart.bar(data);

        chart.title("Load JSON data and create a chart");
        chart.container("container");
        chart.draw();
    });
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.13.1/modules/anychart.data.loadJsonFile-plain

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.1/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/data-adapter.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.13.1/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    <style>
      html, body, #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // To work with the data adapter you need to reference the data adapter script file from AnyChart CDN
    // (https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/data-adapter.min.js for latest or https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.11.1/data-adapter.min.js for the versioned file)

    // Create a chart by JSON config.
    anychart.fromJsonFile("https://cdn.anychart.com/config-samples/line-chart.json", function (chart) {
        chart.title("Create a chart by JSON config");
        chart.container("container");
        chart.draw();
    });
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.13.1/modules/anychart.fromJsonFile-plain